# What script "closes" a DIV if a user clicks outside of it? (version 5 or >, not jQuery)

Tags: javascript

This general type of question has several answers but they all use old script or JQuery.

**What script "closes" a DIV if a user clicks outside of it?**

For example the old code would look something like this

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I believe the first part of the new code would start like this.

```
document.addEventListener("click", modalOff);
```

But after that I get stuck.

```
function modalOff() {
    if (????) {
document.getElementByClassName('modal-a')[0].classList.remove('modal-b'); }
}
```

class `model-a` contains `display: none;`

class `modal-b` includes `display:block;`

by removing `modal-b` the DIV disappears.

But I can't get my mind wrapped around how to tell the browser "if the user clicks outside of the DIV do the next step."  What am I checking for?

Comment: Pass the event variable to `modalOff` then check if `event.target` is equal to the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to use an `addEventListener` to perform this.

```
//Add an event listener for the click event
document.addEventListener('click', closeModal)

//The function is called when the click is found, e is passed as the event variable
function closeModal(e) {

  //Check if the click target is equal to the modal
  if(e.target != modal)
    #Code to hide modal

}
```

The above code should do the trick. Hope this helps.

The "e" signifies the event, when the vent listener is triggered it passes an event object to the function you call. That even has a load of properties such as the element which was, in this case, clicked. This is stored as "target".

Comment: Hi Jonathan, what does the "e" represent on my page?  I think that's the only part I don't understand.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target != modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

As you said, you want to hide if *not* the target of the click...

Or a bit more general:

```
function hideOnOutsideClick(el){
  return function(event){
     var modal=document.getElementById(el);
      if (event.target != modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}
```

So you can do:

```
window.addEventListener("click",hideOnOutsideClick("someid"));
```

Comment: This is the 'old code' as OP puts it I think OP wants to use `addEventListener`

Answer (score 1):

In your `modalOff` function, you need to check if the user clicked the modal *or* an element inside the modal. So you need to do something like this:

```
// check if you clicked on the modal or an object within the modal
var target = event.target;
while (target && target !== document.body && target !== modal) {
    target = target.parentNode;
}
if (target !== modal) {
    // close the modal here
}
```

If the user clicked anywhere within the modal, then at the end of the loop, `target === modal`; if they clicked outside of the modal, then `target !== modal`.